# Molar conductivity

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry

Among $\ce{H+, Li+, K+, Rb+, Cs+}$ in an aqueous medium at infinite dilution at 25 °C, which ions have more ionic molar conductivities than that of $\ce{Na+}$?

I know that Molar conductivity is directly proportional to mobility, which is inversely proportional to hydration energy. By that logic, $\ce{K+, Rb+}$, and $\ce{Cs+}$ have molar conductivities that are greater than $\ce{Na+}$'s, but turns out, $\ce{H+}$'s molar conductivity is also higher in comparison with that of $\ce{Na+}$'s. Why is that so?

Comment: Do you know the ancient fable about a race run between a hare/rabbit and a turtle? Apply it.

Comment: @Poutnik Slow and steady wins the race? But here, the faster the ion moves, more is it's conductivity right?

Comment: No, try to fill the gaps. :-) The turtle won, because of cheating. The turtle ( or rather a land tortoise instead of a sea turtle)   that started the race was not the same as the one that finished it.

Comment: High mobility of hydronium and hydroxide ions is directly related to proton exchange between water molecules and respective ions. See also https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_ChemPRIME_(Moore_et_al.)/11%3A_Reactions_in_Aqueous_Solutions/11.05%3A_Hydrogen_and_Hydroxide_Ions

Comment: A similar question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64984/determining-the-order-of-molar-conductivity/65005#65005

Comment: The [Grotthuss mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grotthuss_mechanism) nicely illustrates the proton exchange on the embedded animated GIF image.